# Wildfly 10 management Rest API

Tags: java, resteasy, wildfly-10

somebody can explain the code below?

i know about RESTEasy client and Jersey AuthenticationFeature... but which means SimpleOperation class and what API it is?

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.digest("admin", "admin");
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(feature);
Entity<SimpleOperation> operation = Entity.entity(
    new SimpleOperation("read-resource", true, "subsystem", "undertow", "server", "default-server"),
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
WebTarget managementResource = client.target("http://localhost:9990/management");
String response = managementResource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    .header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(operation, String.class);
System.out.println(response);
```

from: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The+HTTP+management+API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't find out what the `SimpleOperation` class is, or it's just some made up class for the documentation, you can simply create your own. It is just a simple POJO that the JSON serializer uses to serialize to JSON. If you are unfamiliar with JSON/POJO mapping, here are some tips

- JSON objects (generally) map to Java POJO classes. So `{ }` would map to

  ```
  class SomeClass
  ```
- JSON properties map to Java bean properties. For example if you have a JSON property `firstName`, then you will want a field with getter and setter, with the getter and setter matching the name of the JSON property (with get/set prefix and first letter capitalized)

  ```
  class SomeClass {
      private String firstName;
      public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
      public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName }
  }
  ```

  So if you were to send `new SomeClass("Joao")` as the entity, it would serialize to

  ```
  {"firstName": "Joao"}
  ```

That being said, if you know the format of the JSON you need to send, it shouldn't be too difficult to create your own POJO.

Some other type mappings:

- JSON array generally maps to `List`. So if you have `["hello", "world"]`, you could map it to `List<String>`.
- Or if you have a JSON array of JSON objects, e.g `[{"prop":"value"}, {"prop":"value"}]`, you could map it to a `List<SomeType>`
- Boolean java property *getters* can follow a wider range of naming convention, i.e. `getProperty`, `isProperty`, `hasProperty`

That's pretty much all I can think of for the basics. As an example, looking at one of the example requests from the link you provided

```
{
  "operation":"read-resource", 
  "include-runtime":"true",
  "recursive":"true", 
  "address":["subsystem","undertow","server","default-server"]
}
```

You could map it to a POJO like

```
public class SimpleOperation {
    private String operation;
    @JsonProperty("include-runtime")
    private boolean includeRuntime;
    public boolean recursive;
    private List<String> address;

    public SimpleOperation(String operation, boolean includeRuntime, 
                          boolean recursive, String... address) {
        this.operation = operation;
        this.includeRuntime = includeRuntime;
        this.address = Arrays.asList(address);
    }

    // getters and setters.
}
```

The `@JsonProperty` is so that the Jackson serializer knows how to set the JSON property name. It will be default go off the naming convention I mentioned above, but it will not know to use the `-` in the name, so we explicitly tell it what property name should be.

Then you can do

```
new SimpleOperation("read-resource", true, "subsystem", "undertow", "server", "default-server")
```

And it should be serialized to the above JSON

Comment: Very good! Thank you! I did not understand how the API accepts a post with a JSON statement (the serialized object) ps: the execution returned a error: Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format. Something wrong?

Comment: I don't know. You can register a logging filter `client.register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true)`. It will log details about the request and response. Maybe it will give you some information. But from your comment, it looks like the client is trying to unzip the response, but it's not in gzip format. Maybe the server is setting the content-encoding header to gzip when it's not really in gzip format. I don't know. Just a guess. I would probably need to be able to test it to be of any further help in regards to this :-(

Comment: @João Santana: Did you manage to solve the GZIP-Problem? I've got exactly the same issue when trying to get a response from the Wildfly management REST interface via JAX-RS.