# How to perform system property operations in WildFly via REST?

Tags: java, rest, jboss, wildfly, system-properties

This documentation states that one can perform certain operations for a WildFly server via REST: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/The%20HTTP%20management%20API.html
However, there is no example how to add/remove/read a system property. I have no idea how the HTTP body has to look for those calls.

The answer of the following StackOverflow question says that the class SimpleOperation used in the example does not really exist: [Wildfly 10 management Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772354/wildfly-10-management-rest-api)

I would like to do the following operations:

```
/system-property=BLA:remove
/system-property=BLA:add(value="1,2,3,4")
```

and to read it.

How can I perform these operations via REST with the WildFly HTTP management API? Ideally, I would use a Java API if there was one.

Comment: Are you open to a non-REST API? There is a simple way to do it in Java.

Comment: REST would be much better but you can post an example with a Java API. Are you talking about EJB?

Answer (score 0):

With the `org.wildfly.core:wildfly-controller-client` API you could do something like this:

```java
try (ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create("localhost", 9990)) {
    final ModelNode address = Operations.createAddress("system-property", "test.property");
    ModelNode op = Operations.createRemoveOperation(address);
    ModelNode result = client.execute(op);
    if (!Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(result)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to remove property: " + Operations.getFailureDescription(result).asString());
    }
    op = Operations.createAddOperation(address);
    op.get("value").set("test-value");
    result = client.execute(op);
    if (!Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(result)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to add property: " + Operations.getFailureDescription(result).asString());
    }
}
```

You can use the REST API too, however you'll need to have a way to do digest authentication.

```java
Client client = null;
try {
    final JsonObject json = Json.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("address", Json.createArrayBuilder()
                    .add("system-property")
                    .add("test.property.2"))
            .add("operation", "add")
            .add("value", "test-value")
            .build();
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    final Response response = client.target("http://localhost:9990/management/")
            .request()
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Digest <settings>")
            .post(Entity.json(json));
    System.out.println(response.getStatusInfo());
} finally {
    if (client != null) client.close();
}
```